# Объявление переменной в процедуре

Tags: oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно объявить переменную `count_orders` в процедуре ниже:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INCREASE_EMPLOYEE_SALARY 
(
  EMP_ID IN NUMBER,
  count_orders int := 0
) AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(order_id) 
    INTO count_orders 
    FROM orders 
    WHERE sales_rep_id = emp_id
      AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 2000;
  IF count_orders > 0 THEN
    UPDATE employees
      SET salary = salary * 1.1
      WHERE employee_id = emp_id; 
  END IF;
END INCREASE_EMPLOYEE_SALARY;
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему вы хотите что бы count_orders была локальной переменной, а не параметром процедуры. Тогда ее следует объявлять так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INCREASE_EMPLOYEE_SALARY 
(
  EMP_ID IN NUMBER
)
AS
 count_orders int := 0;
BEGIN
 ...
```

Т.е. локальные переменные объявляются после слова `AS`.

Но в данном, конкретном, примере переменная вам вообще не нужна. Ибо запрос можно было сформулировать так:

```
UPDATE employees
   SET salary = salary * 1.1
 WHERE exists(SELECT 1 FROM orders
               WHERE sales_rep_id = emp_id
                 AND order_date between TO_DATE('01012000','DDMMYYYY')
                                    and TO_DATE('31122000','DDMMYYYY')
             )
   AND employee_id = emp_id;
```

Даты я предпочитаю проверять всегда именно указанным выше способом, потому как применение функций (в т.ч. и extract) к колонке замедляет выборку.